# Magento not compatible with IE or Firefox

Tags: internet-explorer, magento, firefox, magento-1.6, incompatibility

I don't know if this is a theme issue or what but I am having a strange issue with IE and Firefox. Just happened this week with no changes to the website or store. I have looked everywhere online and saw someone on here with a similar issue. I promise I am not trying to advertise. Just look at the sidebar. It pushed the sidebar content to the bottom of the page and the sidebar in the middle of all the products. If you look at it on chrome you will see how it should look. Also works fine on mobile devices.

www.sanitred.com/shop

I saw another post where the guy put the link to his store saying he was advertising. I assure you this isn't the case. I really want to get this fixed. Can someone please help?

Magento ver. 1.6.2.0

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it belongs on either the Magento or WebUsers stackexchange site

Comment: Sorry, First time on this site and wasn't sure how to use it. Much apologies. Next time I will be more careful where I post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a table cell with a width set to 600px:

```
<td width="600" rowspan="2" valign="top">
    <div class="main-container col2-left-layout">
        <!-- More HTML -->
    </div>
</td>
```

Find the template that contains that markup and remove `width="600"` and it should work as expected.

Bonus advice you didn't ask for: I highly recommend not using tables. Tables are for tabular data, not layout. Anything you can do with tables for layout can just as easily be done with CSS. Maintaing a site built with tables is not only non-semantic, it becomes extremely hard to maintain over time, especially when you're building a site with Magento which has so many moving parts.

Comment: Hey man I really appreciate the advice. Unfortunately I didn't get to create this mess. My company just bought this company not long ago and this came with it. I mainly work out of wordpress which is much easier and less stressful than static HTML sites. I am trying to convince my boss to let me rebuild the whole site. Our site is becoming unbareable to maintain. Everything is outdated and done poorly from the start. Anyways. You've been great and really appreciate your help.

Comment: No worries, I totally understand! Credit to you for going the extra mile to make things better. If I answered your question, would you mind to accept it?

Comment: Yes you did, It works perfectly thanks to you. You're a blessing. I clicked the check mark. Is that accepting it? I also tried to give you an up but it won't let me unfortunately. This community is neat. I will try to be active in it. If I did not accept it properly of give you credit properly please let me know. Thanks once again!

Comment: You did it correctly, thank you! I agree, this is a great community. As a heads up, until you get settled you may find people making comments like @JK did. They aren't being unkind, they are just making sure things are held to standard. I've found folks around here are super helpful, and once you have more reputation you have more privilege (like commenting on other people's posts). In fact, our comments may be pruned -Stack Overflow is about factual answers, not discussion. All that to say, welcome!